# node.js script not connecting to mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

When i run my node.js script i get this error:

http://i.gyazo.com/4abc4f518db0de3cb36e34a9fa163e22.png

I was reading a similar error and the guy said it was because the script wasn't connecting to the mysql database. I've tried all of the different logins i can think of and it still wont work. I have tried connecting with no credentials and i get the same error. These are the current credentials i am using to log in:

host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'mypassword',
  database : 'milky',

The code where the error comes from:

```
                    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `value` FROM `info` WHERE `name`=\'maxitems\'', function(err, row, fields) {
                        if(offer.items_to_receive.length > row[0].value) {
                            offers.declineOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid});
                            offer.items_to_receive = [];
                            mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO `messages` (`userid`,`msg`,`from`) VALUES (\''+offer.steamid_other+'\',\'toomuch\',\'System\')', function(err, row, fields) {});
                            return;
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the error message. Images stored on other sites may become unavailable in the future.

Comment: And post a bit of your code

Comment: I can't really see much of the problem, because you posted too less code and error logs. But I think that you saved a SQL-Response (not the actual terminus, I know) in the variable row? So I think you should access it with row['column-name']. But I am not sure.

Comment: I dont think there is anything wrong with the actual search since when i search for it on the actual database using the same command it works.